# $\lim_{x \to 0}(f+g)$ if $\lim_{x \to 0}g$ does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\infty$ and let $g(x)=\sin(\frac{1}{x})$. I know that $g$ does not have a limit at $x=0$, but what about $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(f(x)+g(x))$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $$f(x)+g(x)=f(x) \left( 1+\frac{g(x)}{f(x)} \right)$$ and notice that the fraction tends to zero since the numerator is bounded and the denominator diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sin(x)$ is bounded for all $x$ then $\sin(1/x)$ is also bounded.

Hence the limit is infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Always limit is infinity considering your problem.

Comment: A rather synthetic answer.

Comment: The statement is true, but it's rather useless to the OP, since it gives no explanation at all.